# vim search and replace using current line as reference point

Tags: vim

Is there a way to specify search and replace range using the current line as a reference?
I can specify range using explicit line numbers like

```
:5,15s/foo/bar/g
```

to do the search and replace on only lines 5 to 15.  How to specify a range like "from the current line to 10 lines below (or above) the current line"?

Comment: have you checked `:h range` ?

Comment: @Kent: In my recent Vim, that goes to the `range()` documentation, unfortunately. But `:range` will do the trick.

Comment: @IngoKarkat interesting i have 7.3.1287. `:h range` brings me there. (same as `:h :range`)

Comment: @Kent: Really interesting. For me, it seems to depend on Windows (`range()` first) vs. Linux (`:range` first), but I don't have identical versions. I'll make a note to investigate further.

Comment: Vim's search and replace feature is powerful.  Here you can get what you asked for https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Search_and_replace

Answer (score 149, accepted):

You can use `.` for the current position, and `.+10` for 10 lines down:

```
:.,.+10s/foo/bar/g
```

Some other useful ranges:

- `%` for the whole file. Example: `:%s/foo/bar/g`.
- `'<,'>` for the lines of visually selected block. This might get you more than you want of the visual selection starts or ends in the middle of a line.  The whole line is included.
- `'a,'b` from mark a to mark b.
- `.,$` from the current line to the end of the file.

Comment: For those counting characters, neither `.` is required in that expression.  Thus, `:,+10s/foo/bar/g` is equivalent.

Answer (score 30):

`:help :range` gives you all the details; you can do quite sophisticated things, e.g. `:'a;/pat1/-1`.

For ranges starting from the current line, a neat trick is to start command-line mode by prefixing the `:` with a count: E.g. `5:` turns into `:.,.+4`.

Protip: Learn how to look up commands and navigate the built-in `:help`; it is comprehensive and offers many tips. You won't learn Vim as fast as other editors, but if you commit to continuous learning, it'll prove a very powerful and efficient editor.

Comment: +1 for that `5:` trick.  That's slick.  It can be found at `:help N:`, or just under `:help :range` if you're willing to scroll a bit more.