# How to search and replace in current line only?

Tags: vim, replace

I see [how to search and replace in specific lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17319557/search-and-replace-in-vim-in-specific-lines), specifying by line number, and [how to search and replace using the current line as reference to a number of lines down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18020381/vim-search-and-replace-using-current-line-as-reference-point).

**How do I search and replace in the current line only?** I'm looking for a simple solution that does not involve specifying line numbers as the linked solutions do.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

Replace all occurrences of `str1` with `str2` in certain line:

```
:s/str1/str2/g
```

remove the `g` option if you want to replace only the first occurrence.

Comment: The funny thing is after all these years I've forgotten how to do this and end up searching my own answer to bring back the memory. :-)

Answer (score 60):

You can use `.` for the current line, like:

```
:.s/old/new/
```

This will change `old` by `new` in the current line only.

Comment: This will change only the first occurence

Comment: @dlmeetei: Yes, it will. Just add `g` flag for changing all occurrences. The question is `how to search and replace in current line only?`, I've answered with dot is the way to consider the current line.

Comment: Yes, I thought You will be updating your answer with `g` and hence commented as a reminder

Comment: Why to use the dot? I mean I know that the dot is the current line, but this is the default in the `s//` command. Is there any difference in using the dot vs not using it?

Comment: Note: to replace all occurrences in the current line: `.s/old/new/g`

Answer (score 20):

If you want to search and replace all of the matched word in the current line, you could easily use simple `substitute (s)` with `g` modifier in command mode.

```
:s/search/replace/g
```

If you just want to search and replace the first matched word in the current line, just move away the `g` modifier from your command.

```
:s/search/replace/
```

Ref: `:help substitute`

Answer (score 12):

Confirm (`c`) and Replace :

```
:s/foo/bar/gc
```

Find the occurrence of 'foo', and before replacing it with 'bar' ask for confirmation.

Vim gives you these options :

```
replace with bar (y/n/a/q/l/^E/^Y)?
```

- `y` - yes
- `n` - no
- `a` - replace all occurrences
- `q` - quit
- `l` - replace the current and stop (last)
- `^E` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>) - scroll down
- `^Y` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd>) - scroll up

Now, in your case you can use the combination of `y`, `n` and `l` to achieve your purpose.