# How to add text before the first occurence of a character in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have the text

```
af_ZA_work_013_A;135.300;150.203;Spreker-A;;;[no-speech] #mm
af_ZA_work_013_A;135.300;150.207;Spreker-B;;;[no-speech] #something
```

I want to add `.wav` before the first `;` in each line, so I would get

```
af_ZA_work_013_A.wav;135.300;150.203;Spreker-A;;;[no-speech] #mm
af_ZA_work_013_A.wav;135.300;150.207;Spreker-B;;;[no-speech] #something
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen well no since I have the same data but different names. so I need to specifically find ; and add .wav in front of it.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you but it doesnt. it would give me ```af_ZA_work_013_A.wav;135.300.wav;150.203.wav;Spreker-A;;;[no-speech] #mm```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Vim, how to search and replace in current line only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46181488/in-vim-how-to-search-and-replace-in-current-line-only)

Comment: @jeremysprofile no it doesn't! Okay everyone so basically I need to find the first ```;``` and replace is with ```.wav;``` i don't care about the rest of the text. Please see the difference between input and output. Also I have to do it globally because I have multiple lines of data

Comment: You should edit the question when adding information to your question, rather than including it in a comment, so other answerers can see the full question. It is currently unclear whether you mean the first `;` in the file or in each line, since your example text is one line.

Comment: @jeremysprofile updated it with multiple lines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s/search_regex/replace_regex/` will linewise execute your find and replace.

By default, this is done only on the current line, and only on the first match of `search_regex` on the current line.

Prepending `%` (`%s/search/replace/`) will execute your find and replace on **all** lines in the file, doing at most one replacement per line. You can give ranges (`1,3s` will execute on lines 1-3) or other line modifiers, but this isn't relevant here.

Appending `g` (`s/search/replace/g`) will do multiple replaces per line. Again, not relevant here, but useful for other scenarios.

You can search for `;` and replace with `.wav;` (there are ways to keep the search term and add to it [using capture groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902089/vim-regex-capture-groups-bau-byau-ceu-cyeu) but for one static character it's faster to just retype it).

**TL;DR:** `:%s/;/.wav;/` does what you want.